# How to include time slot breaks in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the disponibility of a user , with start , end time and break start and end , 
i want to add the break time between Lun_mat_de[1] and Lun_apres_a[0]
when i add to the While loop `||` i got `http 500 error`

This is the controller :

```
 public function rdv( $ID)

    {
         $model=doc::findOrFail($ID);
         $ReturnArray = array ();// Define output
         $StartTime    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[0]) ; //Get Timestamp
         $EndTime      = strtotime ($model->Lun_apres_a[1]); //Get Timestamp
         $break_start = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[1]) ; // break start
         $break_end   = strtotime ($model->Lun_apres_a[0]);// break end
         $duration = '60';
            $AddMins  = $duration * 60;
           while ($StartTime <= $break_start || $EndTime >=$break_end ) //Run loop
            {
                $ReturnArray[] = date ("G:i", $StartTime);
                $StartTime += $AddMins; //Endtime check
            }
         return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=> $model],['jaja'=>$ReturnArray] );

    }
```

and this is the view :

```
 @foreach($jaja as $ja)
     <button class="btn btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Have you tried that with storing that condition in one variable and passing that in that loop?

Comment: No i didn't but how can i do it ? @MaulikShah

Comment: That's simple! 
`$breakConditions = $StartTime <= $break_start || $EndTime >=$break_end
while($breakConditions) { ...}`
Hope it works:)

Comment: `HTTP ERROR 500` i got this error again  :/

Comment: Can you please try to `dd` your results it seems problem with passing data to view. Before you return view print your `$model` and `$ReturnArray`.  Try to debug this. If that was problem you have pass data differently!

Comment: i add dd and i get `true`

Comment: Before return? Does it is correct data what you want?

Comment: yes the data is correct

Comment: and yes before return

Comment: i guess While Loop causing 500 Internal Server error

Comment: Then issue is with returning your data to view. Try to pass data like this, `return view ('/rendezvous')->with(['go'=> $model, 'jaja'=>$ReturnArray] );`
Nope issue is with passing data to view. As you get correct data before return and just after that is causing problems so:)

Comment: `Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 536870920 bytes)` what does this mean ?

Comment: Not have an idea about this, you can check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/allowed-memory-size-of-1610612736-bytes-exhausted and for passing data you can find better options in laravel doc or on stackoverflow.

It seems problem is with passing the data not more than that try this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thank you for yr Help ;)

Comment: @MaulikShah when i remove this  `|| $EndTime >=$break_end ` the `HTTP  error` dispear

Comment: Try to Use them in brackets separately `($StartTime <= $break_start) || ($EndTime >=$break_end)`

Comment: Now i'm sure that the problem is in the while condition when adding this `($EndTime >=$break_end)`